# Combine two sequences with different types

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have two classes which defined like this:

```
class Foo
{
  public string name {get; set;}
  public long number {get; set;}
}

class Bar
{
  //some properties

  public string otherName {get; set;}
  public long otherNumber {get; set;}
}
```

How to combine two `IEnumerable` sequences of these two types to a new anonymous type which consists of a combination of properties of both classes.

Example:

```
Foo:
name1 - number1
name2 - number2
name3 - number3

Bar:
otherName1 - otherNumber1
OtherName2 - otherNumber2

Desired Result:
name1 - number1
name2 - number2
name3 - number3
otherName1 - otherNumber1
OtherName2 - otherNumber2
```

I tried `Zip`function in linq with no luck.

Comment: Anonymous type including "name", "number", "othername" and "othernumber", right?

Comment: Use `Concat`. First have common base class or interface, then concat the two list.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Actually I want to combine these two properties into one. Take a look to my example.

Comment: @nawfal I know how `Concat` works, but the question is about two different classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
    var result = efoo.Select(x => new { x = x.name, y = x.number })
                     .Concat(ebar.Select(x => new { x = x.otherName, y = x.otherNumber }));
```

`result` is an enumerable of anonymous type having `x`, `y` as properties. You can iterate through this sequence with a normal `foreach` loop:

```
   foreach (var i in result)
   {
        string name = i.x;
        long number = i.y;
   }
```

Comment: Just curious as I'm not a .NET guy: does C# compiler merge these two anonymous classes (from two `Select`s respectively)?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Yes, it does concatenate them into a new sequence of an anonymous type, with `x`, `y` properties, as pointed out in my answer. You can then iterate through this sequence with a normal `foreach` loop.

Comment: That's interesting, I have never known about such a strategy, thanks. :) And what if I declare such classes in different methods (within the same class) -- how would the compiler deal with them? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv it is considered as the same type across one assembly if signature matches. Anonymous types are per assembly basis.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what's the point of concatenating or how the later use is gonna be. You could cast it to `IEnumerable<object>` and then do a `Concat`, something like:

```
var result = foos.Cast<object>().Concat(bars.Cast<object>());
```

The ideal way to do is may be have common base class or interface and use that in place of `object`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = FooList.Select(t=> new { a = t.name, b = t.number})
                    .Concat(
                       BarList.Select(t => new { a = t.othername, b = t.othernumber}));
```

If you want to "merge" the results then use Union instead of Concat -- but in that case you will need a Compare function for the element type.